# JQuery Ajax form only sending first post variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to "post" some data to a php script. Of the 3 variables being sent, only the first one seems to be getting sent. What am I not seeing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newproject").ajaxForm({
        url: '/ajax/newproject.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'name=' + $('name').val() + '&username=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>&sessionid=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'success') $('#returnMessage').attr('class', 'good');
            else $('#returnMessage').attr('class', 'bad');
            $('#returnMessage').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess you really have a name tag, as that is being sent, for the other two, look at the source in a browser to see that the correct values are being echo'ed.

Comment: I have. When I view the page source, both echoed variables are there as they should be.
`data: 'name=myproject&username=sam&sessionid=50c53879a3f0b',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Array data:

```
$("#newproject").ajaxForm({
    url: '/ajax/newproject.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        name: $('name').val(),
        username: '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>',
        sessionid: '<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'success') $('#returnMessage').attr('class', 'good');
        else $('#returnMessage').attr('class', 'bad');
        $('#returnMessage').html(data);
    }
});
```

You can retrieve post data using $_POST['name'], $_POST['username'], etc.

Comment: I am not sure since your original code seems right. From jquery.ajax docs the data option can contain either a query string of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`, or a map of the form `{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}`. The possibility is that either your username/sessionid contains not allowed character in query string.